# How fetch data from mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor application, on the server side, I need to get data from Mongo, analyse and update it in Mongo if neсessary. In the database, I have an array of objects:

```
{ "0" : { "title" : "This is title", "description" : "This is description", "link" : "http://123435", "pubDate" : "16 Oct 2014 20:46:00 +0400" }, "1" : { }, "3" : { } etc
```

I'm try get data from Mongo: var savedNews = News.find().fetch(), there News is my collection. And I see in debugger array of this type:

```
    0: "_id"="uuTOncmcIoIkfc",
    1: "_id"="mcmroidewiuIpf" 
    etc
```

I understand this is _id's, but I need access to the fields of objects. In Mongo console I can see my real objects if I type db.news.find(); How I can get data in the form of array or object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Fetch() return an array, those records you get can get probably expanded, if not, maybe you don't publish all of this data.
For example, you should be able to get to data like this:

```
temp = Collection.find({_id:"1"}).fetch();
temp[0].variable
```

Or simply

```
temp = Collection.find({_id:"1"}).fetch()[0].variable;
```

If you need just one record try using findOne, this return just one array, so no use of fetch() or [] is required

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately my experience in mongo is very small. I think I insert data in non correct format. I try change object format before insertion in Mongo: {"items": [{}, {},{} ...]} and I can see this array after fetching it's from Mongo. Now I see array with "_id" and array of items.

Comment: Glad it worked. And I also highly recommend using console.log(Collection.find().fetch()); to see if everything looks as expected